# How to do classification without class labels?

Tags: classification, clustering

I am comparing different classification and clustering methods for analyzing my game (called Memori) data. It is about diagnosing kids with VSMD.

I have fount a dataset from 1980s with only 2 features and it doesn't have any labels (diagnosed/not diagnosed) on it. I managed to add new features for my own dataset, I have about 25 features now. But I have a problem: since I don't have the labels for the original data, I don't know how to be sure that my game diagnoses well.

Any suggestions on how I can proceed?

Comment: You can work it out and add the labels yourself. It's manual work.

Comment: you can try to apply a clustering algorithm for external 80s dataset and then manually attach label to those clusters. At least you won't have to manually review every data sample then.

Comment: I would first do some meaningful visualizations, and see if there is a good way to do clustering. Afterwords you can either add labels based on clustering, or do it manually as suggested by @Student T.

Comment: I think there's a simple answer and the answer is "no".  It sounds to me like any method would be cheating.

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on old data and "magic" to predict ("diagnose") anything.

Get fresh data.

Much of the success we've been seeing from machine learning is because these companies have collected a massive amount of (fresh) data well-suited for their purpose.

So by any means, get new labeled data.

In particular in medicine, which has a lot of false results due to data reuse.